# Impact on site performance due to use ObjectCache from System..Runtime.Caching

Tags: performance, asp.net-mvc-3, cpu-usage, objectcache

I'm working on an online shopping cart site which is in ASP.NET MVC3. I'm using ObjectCache with  policy Absolute Expiration for caching some products.

How does it work? Is it starting one type of counter/timer or something to expire caching items?
Does it have impact on CPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all your answers here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597.aspx